# Failed Autosys jobs names within a list of jobs

Tags: linux, jobs, autosys

I am looking for all the autosys jobs that are in failed state by using the command

```
 autorep -J %<<name>>% | grep "FA"
```

However I am looking to get all such failed jobs whose names match within a list of ids.

For example I have 4 failed jobs - `job_1, job_2, job_3, job_4`

I only want to return the jobs with names which have 1 and 2 in them. So how would I do that?

Please note, the starting part of the jobname is not the same in the actual scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to match all failed jobs with characters ABC or DEF in them:

```
autorep -J ALL | grep -e '\(ABC\|DEF\).*FA'
```